# SharePoint List View Complex Filter Logic

Tags: list, list-view, filter

I'm creating a SP list view and trying to apply a filter to it without creating calculating columns to compare:

Show items only when the following is true:

- Status equals to "Cancelled" AND Cancelled Date is greater than or equal to [TODAY]-180 AND Region equals to "1";
  **OR**
- Status equals to "Rejected" AND Rejected Date is greater than or equal to [TODAY]-180 AND Region equals to "1"

Below is what I've tried. Most likely it's the order of the AND/ORs but I can't seem to figure it out.

[image: This is what I've tried].

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to merge them up so that you select items that you need in view. You can make this as

> (Status equals to "Cancelled" OR Status equals to "Rejected" ) AND
> (Cancelled Date >= [TODAY]-180 OR Rejected Date >= [TODAY]-180) AND
> (Region equals to "1")

That should give you correct items.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have saved me a bottle of Tylenol for the headache!